# is that OK I define a static Application object inside the custom Application class for reference in Android?

Tags: android, static, global

My problem is that I have some asynctasks which need my custom Application object to invove some functions. Eachtime I want to create an asynctask, I had to pass into the application object or current context into it.

I am thinking what if I made the application object static.

> class MyApp extends Application {
>
> > > static MyApp app;
> > >
> > > public onCreate() {
> > >       app = this;
> > >       }
>
> }

Then I can get this global application object (MyApp.app) without have to pass the context in.

is that ok? any risk?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do that,
just create a subclass of Application and declare your own application in the manifest.

```
<Application
    android:name="blah.YourApplication">
</Application>
```

then to access it, you just need an Activity or Service instance to getApplication() and cast it to your "YourApplication" class.

Since  you want to access  "YourApplication" in an AsyncTask subclass, you should pass the service or activity that started your AsyncTask to  your "AsyncTask" subclass so that you could access  "YourApplication" inside.

Comment: I do not want to pass the service or activity into, it is annoying. So I thought to use a static variable.

Comment: well in that case, your approach should be fine.  Anyway there is only one instance of "Application" class in the life cycle of your App.